# How to query from the Pointer in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have created a Pointer in ParseClass I want to query from the Pointer added I have created ParseObject class so how can set the ParseObject for querying the pointer.

Games Parse class has Pointer 'Places'

```
@ParseClassName("Games")
public class Offers extends ParseObject{

        public String getPlaceName() {
            return getString(getParseObject("Places").getString("PlaceName"));
        }
```

Comment: its tack first to ParseObject & store it to direct pointer

Comment: @HardikParmar how to go about it can write down the code?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get Games objects with related Places data, you should use 'include' in the query.

```
ParseQuery<Offers> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Offers.class);
//query.equalTo("objectId", "gameId");
query.include("Places");
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<Offers>() {
    @Override
    public void done(Offers obj, ParseException e) {
        if(e!=null) {
            Log.e("err", e.getMessage());
        }
        else {
            Log.d("PlaceName", obj.getParseObject("Places").getString("PlaceName"));
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to get related data by pointer(ParseObject which only contains id)

```
            ParseObject place = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Places","id");
            place.fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    //do what you want
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

try it

```
        final ArrayList<ParseObject> Places = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> offer = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("className");

    offer.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // success
                for (ParseObject parseObject : objects) {
                    Places.add(parseObject.getParseObject("Places"));
                }

                Log.e("TAG ", "get parse pointer object " + Places.size());
            } else {
                // fail
            }
        }
    });
```